# Docker: Why does my project have a .env file?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables, dockerfile

I'm working on a group project involving Docker that has a `.env` file, which looks like this:

```
DATABASE_URL=xxx
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=xxx
SECRET_KEY=xxx
```

Couldn't this just be declared inside the `Dockerfile`? If so, what is the advantage of making a `.env` file?

Not sure if I'm going in the right direction with this, but [this Docker Docs page](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution) says (emphasis my own):

> Your configuration options can contain environment variables. Compose
>   uses the variable values from the shell environment in which
>   `docker-compose` is run. For example, suppose the shell contains
>   `POSTGRES_VERSION=9.3` and you supply this configuration:
>
> `db:`
>
> ```
>   `image: "postgres:${POSTGRES_VERSION}"`
> ```
>
> When you run `docker-compose` up with this configuration, Compose looks for the `POSTGRES_VERSION` environment variable in the shell and substitutes its value in. For this example, Compose resolves the image to `postgres:9.3` before running the configuration.
>
> If an environment variable is not set, Compose substitutes with an empty string. In the example above, if `POSTGRES_VERSION` is not set, the value for the image option is `postgres:`.
>
> **You can set default values for environment variables using a `.env` file, which Compose automatically looks for. Values set in the shell environment override those set in the `.env` file.**

**If we're using a `.env` file, then wouldn't I see some `${...}` syntax in our `docker-compose.yml` file? I don't see anything like that, though.**

Here's our `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '3'

services:
    server:
        build:
            context: ./server
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        env_file: .env.dev
        command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - ./server:/app
        ports:
            - "8500:8000"
        depends_on:
            - db
        stdin_open: true
        tty: true

    db:
        image: postgres

    client:
        build:
            context: ./client
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        command: bash -c "npm install; npm run start"
        volumes:
            - ./client:/app
            - /app/node_modules
        ports:
            - "3000:3000"
        depends_on:
            - server
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Idea there is probably to have a place to keep secrets separated from docker-compose.yml, which you then can keep in VCS and/or share.

Comment: I see -- why keep it a secret? So that the docker-compose.yml could be public use for others but then set private parameters in a custom file (which is `.env`)?

Comment: Compiling your database hostname or session cookie signing secret into a binary that anyone can easily read (which would be the effect of putting it in the Dockerfile) isn't a great idea.  Those things will probably be different every time you deploy the image.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks @DavidMaze